# Scraping only when a change is detected?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, screen-scraping, casperjs

My bank has a really simple login system. Using casperjs I have been able to pull my latest account balance and my last transaction. There are many ways to scrape data off the Internet, I just used Casperjs to test out its capabilities.I checked with the bank and they say- as long as it's my bank account, it's no problem.

Here's the technical problem I'm having to deal with: the bank limits the number of login to ~ 40 a day. Should the number of logins go above that. It will lock me out of my account for 6 hours. (Also, the system logs me out every 20 minutes- irrelevant of the action)

What I'm trying to do figure out is:
is there a way to only run a scraping function if a transaction has occurred and there is a change in the account balance?

Scraping is normally done on a timely basis for simplicity. What can I implement that is a push notification style scraping mechanism?

The objective is to get a message/email Everytime a transaction has occurred (with a Max 3-4 minute delay) while not getting locked out of the system.

Any creative answers would do too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How would you know that a transaction has occurred without logging in? If the online banking site is programmed well, you will have to log in.

Little arithmetic:

- ~ 40 logins per 24 hours
- log out after 20 minutes
- results in login every 24h/39 ~ 37 minutes without risking lock out
- Which means you have a delay of at most 17 minutes (This is waaay too much without new information *:)* )

You're obviously not awake the whole 24 hours.

- ~ 40 logins per 16 hours
- log out after 20 minutes
- results in login every 16h/39 ~ 24.6 minutes without risking lock out
- Which means you have a delay of at most 5 minutes (This is seems acceptable)

Talk to your bank, whether they provide an API. If you get locked out of your account, they might get suspicious of your activity and permanently lock your account.

Since CasperJS is asynchronous, you will have to use your scraping function recursively.

```
var casper = require("casper").create(),
    url = "your bank url",
    counter = 0;

function login(){
    counter++;
    this.thenOpen(url, function(){
        this.fillSelectors("login form selector", {
            "username selector": "username",
            "password selector": "password",
            // more if necessary
        }, true); // automatically submit
    });
}

function scrape(){
    // do your thing
}

function run(){
    if (counter == 39) {
        counter = 0;
        this.wait(8 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
            .then(run);
    } else if (this.exists("selector which shows that you are logged in")) {
        this.then(scrape)
            .wait(30 * 1000)
            .then(run);
    } else if (this.exists("selector which shows that you where automatically logged out")) {
        this.wait(5 * 60 * 1000)
            .then(login)
            .then(run);
    } else {
        this.then(login)
            .then(run);
    }
}

casper.start().then(run).run();
```

Comment: Hi Artjom, thanks for your reply.

sure that makes sense, lets shrink our active period to 16. Fundementally, the bank has no interest in providing an api. Based on my conversations with them - they claim security reasons, but i think they're just lazy.
(note that i'm in a third world country, everything takes longer here)

I am checking for effectively a table to see if there are any changes.
What methods do i need to implement on casperjs to ensure that we dont ever log out, yet refresh the page every 30 seconds or so and wait for a change.

Thanks once again.

Comment: I added a script which should work for you. It has the assumption that CasperJS is never stopped. You might want to run it only for 16 hours and then re-run it with cron or something like that.

Comment: Hey! this might work. let me try it out and let you know! thanks